# Filtering then sorting object array by date

Tags: javascript, filter

I am trying to filter the json by it's start and end date by comparing it to the current date. And I want to sort the filtered json by its start date. Here's what I've done so far

```
dateNow = new Date();
filteredJson = ufjson.filter((item, index) => item.start_date <= dateNow && item.end_date <= dateNow);
```

However the filter doesn't work. I dont get results.

Here's my sample json

```
ufjson = [
  {
    amount: '50',
    discount: '0',
    start_date: '2021-01-01T18:24:18.790+08:00',
    end_date: '2020-01-29T18:24:18.790+08:00',
  },
  {
    amount: '100',
    discount: '10',
    start_date: '2021-01-05T18:24:18.790+08:00',
    end_date: '2020-01-25T18:24:18.790+08:00',
  },
 ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: No. Cause im using the right opperands as far as i know

Comment: You're comparing dates and strings. Change your strings to dates. Also, that's not JSON; JSON is a text format. That's just an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did was comparing two string. You first have to change them to Number.
You can do this:

```
var ufjson = [
  {
    amount: "50",
    discount: "0",
    start_date: "2021-01-01T18:24:18.790+08:00",
    end_date: "2020-01-29T18:24:18.790+08:00",
  },
  {
    amount: "100",
    discount: "10",
    start_date: "2021-01-21T18:24:18.790+08:00",
    end_date: "2020-01-25T18:24:18.790+08:00",
  },
];

var dateNow = new Date();
var filteredJson = ufjson.filter(
  (item, index) =>
    new Date(item.start_date).getTime() <= dateNow.getTime() &&
    new Date(item.end_date).getTime() <= dateNow.getTime()
);

console.log("item:", filteredJson);
```

I just changed second date start.